# How to replace a number within a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In my programming class we have a practice problem where the objective is to replace the second of two consecutive numbers in a list with a zero, if the numbers are equal.

**For Example:**

`def zeroDuplicates([1,5,2,7,7])` would output `[1,5,2,7,0]`

However, when I attempt to do this, I always get an error.
What I have so far is the following:

```
def zeroDuplicates(nums):
    count =0
    for n in nums:
        if n == nums[n-1]:
             nums.replace[n,0]
    return nums
```

Error message when I run this program:

```
"Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'"
```

Comment: What error do you get? Always include the exact error messages when asking a question.

Comment: Note that `n` is not the index of the value but the value itself in your for loop.

Comment: It says: "Error: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'"

Comment: What is `replace` ? is it a function? why you use it like this `[]`

Comment: You should also consider what your code should be doing when there are 3 repetitions, or maybe a repetition later down the list

Comment: There are a few possible implementations, but the it might be worth defining the behavior of the fringe cases, such as triple values, or a double proceeded by a 0, etc

Answer (score 2):

`n` is an element in your example; not an index. Your program as pseudo-code would replace an element if it equals the element with index of its value minus 1.

Lets make your problem more definitive (robot friendly): you want to iterate from `1` to the length of the list, and if the current elements equals the previous, replace it with a zero.

Now lets translate from English to Python (we use `i` to indicate index):

```
def zeroDuplicates (nums):
    for i in range(1, len(nums)):
         if nums[i] == nums[i-1]:
             nums[i] = 0
    return nums
```

---

Bonus: You can "pythonize" it using list comprehensions and zipping:

```
def zeroDuplicates (nums):
    return [nums[0]] + [(0 if a == b else a) for a, b in zip(nums[1:], nums[:-1])]
```

(for every element and its successor, if they equal the successor equals 0, otherwise it will remain unchanged).

Answer (score 1):

You have another problem that above code won't handle

What If the repeat value occurred not at index -1 place but much before that?

```
values = [1,5,7,2,7,7]

values_added = set()
new_values = []

for val in values:
    if val in values_added:
        new_values.append(0)
    else:
        new_values.append(val)
        values_added.add(val)

print(values_added)

print(new_values)
```

output:

```
{1, 2, 5, 7} # values_added
[1, 5, 7, 2, 0, 0] # new_values
```

Comment: I don't think that's what is asked because the OP explicitly states that "_the objective is to replace the second of two **consecutive** numbers in a list with a zero_"

Comment: @MSeifert True.

Comment: @AdemÖztaş That's not what I am looking for with this code. I need to know if a value has already been added to the list. For which I need to track what I have added to the list and what I haven't. Where as set(Values) will give me all unique values.

Answer (score 0):

Note that your approach also wouldn't work if several values are identical, I would advise to create a new list so you don't compare to potentially changed values. I would recommend using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) which seems a perfect fit in this case:

```
from itertools import groupby

res = []
for item, group in groupby([1,2,3,3,3,3,2,1]):
    identicals = list(group)
    # Append the item
    res.append(item)
    # Extend the list with x zeros where x is the number of successive duplicates
    res.extend([0] * (len(identicals) - 1))

>>> res
[1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
def zero_duplicates(nums):
  items = []
  for item in nums:
      if item not in items:
          items.append(item)
      else:
          items.append(0)
  return items

vals = [1, 5, 2, 7, 7]
print zero_duplicates(vals)
```

Output:

```
[1, 5, 2, 7, 0]
```

**Additional info:**

Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

mixedCase is allowed only in contexts where that's already the prevailing style (e.g. threading.py), to retain backwards compatibility.

Link: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names